# Query content from ID Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

im having troubles to diplay the content from an ID here is an example what im doing.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM home_text";
$select_home_text_query = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $select_home_text_query ) ) {
    $home_content = $row[ '1' ];
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 separator">
        <p class="lead">
            <?php echo $home_content;?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

And here is an image from the database.

**The content is the one i wanted to show**
[image: The content is the one i wanted to show]

Thanks, for the help!.

Comment: where you have established the connection to the database?

Comment: and As you are fetching records as associative array so you should use the feild names like $row['home_id']

Comment: Just printing the entire row will not work. You need to call separately the fields, like echo $home_content[col-name];

Answer (score 1):

Change `$home_content = $row[ '1' ];` ton `$home_content = $row['home_id'];` and use `mysqli_fetch_array` instead.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM home_text";
$select_home_text_query = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $select_home_text_query ) ) {
    $home_content = $row['home_id'];
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 separator">
        <p class="lead">
            <?php echo $home_content;?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Why use `mysqli_fetch_array()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`? Using that would return the row as an associative array _and_  as an indexed array, which isn't necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

make

```
$home_content = $row[ '1' ];
```

line to

```
$home_content = $row['home_id'];
```

Comment: The OP is fetching the rows using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` so`$row` should be an associative array containing column names as keys. So unless the OP has a column spcifically named `0`, this should throw an _"undefined index"_.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with `mysqli_fetch_array`, so you can call the data by mentioning the column array, starting at 0 for the first column, 1 for the second, and so on

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM home_text";
$select_home_text_query = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $select_home_text_query ) ) {
    $home_content = $row[0];
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 separator">
        <p class="lead">
            <?php echo $home_content;?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

`mysqli_fetch_assoc`: you will call by the name of the column, without forgetting the quotes. Ex: $ row['home_id'];

`mysqli_fetch_array`: you will call by the column position. Ex: $ row[0];

`mysqli_fetch_object`: you will call it as an object mentioning the name of the column. Ex: $ row->home_id;

Answer (score 0):

Here an update version of your code to handle multiple rows if required if not pass LIMIT 1 to the query.

Here you will have more control and can format the output on the $out variable.

Hope it helps.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM home_text";

$out = '';
$result = $mysql->query( $query );
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $id = $row['home_id];
     $content = $row['home_contents'];
     $names = $row['home_names'];
     //format how you want it on the html
     $out .= " $id | $names | $content";
    }
}

?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 separator">
        <p class="lead">
            <?php echo $out;?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```